# Angularjs ng-click inside directive. ControllerAs connecting issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

`ShowPopover` doesn't work when you click on the directive. Could you please help me identify the cause of the problem?

**Directive:**

```
 angular.module('landingBuilder').directive('popoverDirective', popoverDirective);

        function popoverDirective() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: '/libs/landing-builder/directive/popover-directive/popover-directive.html',
                controller: controller,
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                transclude: true,
                bindToController: true
            };

            function controller($element, $document){
                var vm = this;
                vm.showPopover = showPopover();
                function showPopover() {
                    console.log('show popover');
                };
            }
        }
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="input-layover popup-target" ng-click="vm.showPopover"</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `showPopover()` instead of `showPopover` here.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click=vm.showPopover()>hello</button>',
    controller: controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    transclude: true,
    bindToController: true
  };

  function controller($element, $document) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.showPopover = showPopover;

    function showPopover() {
      console.log('show popover');
    };
  }
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/skcvt0ns/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes.. Thanks. Added it to the answer

Comment: @IgorPonomarenko If it helped.  you should mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ns0pe1ur/

You made some mistakes in your code:

1. it is not proper html
2. you need to call function on ng-click, not inside you controller

Your template should look like this:

```
 <div class="input-layover popup-target" ng-click="vm.showPopover()"></div>
```

And you controller like this:

```
  function controller($element, $document) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.showPopover = showPopover;

    function showPopover() {
      console.log('show popover');
    };
  }
```